# input interrupt error (UV projector)

Tags: usb, hdmi, serial, input-device, interrupts

I am trying to control a UV light projector with a raspberry.
The raspberry recognizes the projector, as in the dmesg it says the product, the manufacturer and the serial number...  but then this error appears.

In the dmesg the error seems to be the following:

--    **usbhid 1-1.4:1.1: couldn't find an input interrupt endpoint**  --

Comment: Seems you need a driver to handle the input interrupt. Do you installed a driver?

Comment: No,
I haven't installed any driver... Do you think I should install a driver to the raspberry? Any recommendations about how doing it?

Answer (score 1):

I do not know something about your UV light projector. But the Raspberry Pi recognizes it, when it is connected by USB. That doesn't mean that it can also handle it. You need a driver. For popular device classes the kernel has drivers built-in so these will work out of the box. But that seems not to be the case with your projector. The error message suggests that there is no driver that is handling the interrupt from the projector. You should look at a driver, maybe a firmware package, for it.

Comment: Thanks!
Do you know where can I find drivers or firmware packages for raspberry 4, and how to proceed to install them?

Appreciate your help

Comment: @nanobio3D Sorry, but I do not know something about your UV light projector and where to get driver/firmware for it. Usually they come as normal Debian packages with extension '*.deb'. Maybe you only get its source files. Then you have to compile it. I would look first at the web site of the manufacturer. Or google `your-UV-light-projector firmware driver`.